# Не могу определить самое длинное слово в файле, python

Tags: python, массивы

Дана следующая задача: "Текстовый файл состоит не более чем из 10^6 символов и содержит только заглавные латинские буквы и десятичные цифры. Определите самое длинное слово. Словом считается любая произвольная последовательность букв." Пробелов в файле нет, только цифры и буквы.

Я составила следующий код:

```
s = open('24.txt').read()
data = []
maxdata = []
for char in s:
    if char in '0123456789':
        data.clear()
    else:
        data.append(char)
        if len(data) > len(maxdata):
            maxdata.clear()
            maxdata = data
print(*maxdata)
```

Но он ничего не печатает. :(
Можете написать, в чём проблема?

Comment: попробуйте print(s) и покажите что выведет хотябы кусочек нам.

Comment: он, собственно, выводит весь файл, вот только фрагмент:

Comment: `824476169865628ASDFG1788886177437521566357664882361915864252327643427728984312599481742276731413193156555293255265394699135118768132`

Comment: `longest = max(map(operator.itemgetter(0), re.finditer(r'[A-Z]+', s)), key=len)`.

Comment: Если вместо списков использовать строки - всё заработает)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь вы присваиваете переменной `maxdata` **ссылку**, которая содержится в переменной `data`. В результате чего у вас обе эти переменные начинают указывать на **один и тот же список**:

```
maxdata = data
```

Поэтому, когда вы дальше по ходу действия программы очищаете список, на который указывает переменная `data`:

```
data.clear()
```

Вы таким образом очищаете тот же самый список, на который указывает и `maxdata` и у вас этот список становится пустым.
Чтобы такого не происходило, вам нужно присвоить `maxdata` ссылку на **копию** списка, на который указывает переменная `data`. Сделать это можно одним из следующих способов:

- `maxdata = data.copy()`
- `maxdata = data[:]`
- `maxdata = list(data)`

Но ещё лучше вместо `data.clear()` использовать `data = []`, чтобы каждую итерацию цикла переменная `data` у вас указывала на новый список (обычно именно так и делают в питоне).